# How do I run a War File in confined SELinux domain on CentOS7?

Tags: java, centos-7, selinux

I am currently working on the deployment of my Java Web Application. This application is available to me as a WAR file. 
 My goal is that the application starts with a limited SELinux startup. This means that it should only have access to what is necessary to run the application. 
Explicitly I want the application to be accessible via one port and have access to multiple folders and nothing more. The application is started by default with `java -jar <app>`. To my knowledge it is not easy to use a Tomcat, because my application needs at least Tomcat 8.5 and the necessary settings regarding SELinux are not set during installation. 
Currently the process is displayed as unconfined_u. 
One problem is that the Java module for SELinux is not available on CentOS 7.
 In the beginning I tried the following two things, without success: https://www.schakko.de/2018/08/28/running-spring-boot-jar-service-selinux-enabled/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26068817/where-is-the-java-selinux-policy-module-for-centos-7.
Then I tried to write my own label with 
 `sepolicy generate --init <path>/<to>/<app>/<app> -n <app>` and 
 `<app>.sh` 
I tried the same with the used Java (installed with yum).
After that I tried it with a shell script in the same way. I also installed the generated rpm packages. Finally I tried to give the shell script and the war file the type tomcat_exet_t. 
 Although the labels were changed in all attempts as I wanted, the process ran as unconfined_u in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To confine it the default .te file must be extended.
The following line should be added: 
`require {
        type unconfined_t;
}`

```
domain_type(myapp_t)
```

`domain_entry_file(myapp_t, myapp_exec_t)`

`domtrans_pattern(unconfined_t,myapp_exec_t, myapp_t)`